# Is a beracha given in writing effective?

Tags: blessing, writing-printing, speech-talking

To whatever extent giving someone a beracha is effective, does a beracha given in writing have the same effect?  Is the efficacy of the beracha somehow tied specifically to speech?

Comment: I'd have to assume a _b'racha_ given in writing is at least *somewhat* effective, as pretty much every _t'shuva_ you read in _t'shuva_ books has one. Are you asking whether it's **as** effective as one given orally?

Comment: @msh210 Sometimes a b'racha is a greeting or formality.